# Get average of multiple ranks in mysql

Tags: mysql, correlation

I am trying to calculate the spearmans rank correlation for some data in mysql. For this I need to rank my data on a descending order. I got this working but when 2 rows have the same variable the rank should be the average of the 2 or more ranks.
As an example here is some example data with the current ranks and the expected ranks

```
| id|var|rank|
| 8 | 1 | 1  |
| 2 | 2 | 2  | # rank should be 2.5
| 6 | 2 | 3  | # rank should be 2.5 
| 4 | 3 | 4  | 
| 5 | 4 | 5  | 
| 1 | 5 | 6  | 
| 3 | 6 | 7  | # rank should be 8
| 7 | 6 | 8  | # rank should be 8
| 9 | 6 | 9  | # rank should be 8
```

My query looks like this right now:

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SET @rownum2 := 0;
SELECT  rank_x.id, rank_x.var1, rank_x.rk_x
FROM 
    (SELECT id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rk_x, var1
     FROM sampledata order by var1 asc) as rank_x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by assigning the sequential number and then taking the average.  This requires some nested subqueries, but is doable.  The idea is:

- First assign the sequential value
- Then find the max for each id.
- Then find the min
- Then take the average

The query looks like:

```
SELECT id, var1, (minrn + maxrn) / 2
FROM (SELECT sd.*,
             (@maxrn := if(@v2 = var1, @maxrn,
                           if(@v2 := var1, rn, rn)
                          )
             ) as maxrn
      FROM (SELECT  sd.*,
                    (@minrn := if(@v = var1, @minrn,
                                  if(@v := var1, rn, rn)
                                 )
                    ) as minrn
            FROM (SELECT id, var1, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
                  FROM sampledata sd CROSS JOIN
                       (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
                  ORDER BY var1 asc
                 ) sd CROSS JOIN
                 (SELECT @minrn := 0, @v := -1) vars
            ORDER BY var1, rn
           ) sd CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @maxrn := 0, @v2 := -1) vars
      ORDER BY var1, rn desc
     ) sd;
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works great! the only mistake you made(i guess) is the "@rn" on the fourth line. i think it should be "rn".
Anyway, perfect solution!